# performSegueWithIdentifier in AppDelegate when any view controller is visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have this method in my AppDelegate when the app receives a local notification. I want it to perform a segue to a view controller when a notification gets received. This works fine when the view controller that is currently visible is the root view controller, but when it's any other view controller it does not work. And I can't access `visibleViewController` because I'm not using a navigation controller. How can I fix this?

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
    NSString *segueId = @"segueToTrigger";
    [self.window.rootViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:segueId sender:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard, give the view controller a storyboard_id. Use

```
    UIViewController * vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"[<your_story_board_id>]"];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window]addSubview:vc.view];
```

Remember to assign `vc` to a strong property, otherwise it will be released out of the function.